# Netsuite Webservices

Tags: web-services, netsuite, saas, suitescript

Using webservices I need to login to netsuite and I have to create session,I have created and modified tokens in netsuite account, i dont know how to use anybody, please suggest how to do. either to perfom this soap or java which way is best I know little bit of java.Kindly send link if any available.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example (MVCE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

[Here's the documentation pertaining to SuiteTalk](https://ursuscode.com/public/netsuitehelp/book_N3412393.html)

[SuiteTalk (Web Services) Records Guide](https://ursuscode.com/public/netsuitehelp/SuiteTalkWebServicesRecordsGuide.pdf)

[SuiteTalk (Web Services) Platform Guide](https://ursuscode.com/public/netsuitehelp/SuiteTalkWebServicesPlatformGuide.pdf)

You will find some SOAP examples as well as Java and PHP. I have personally used the PHP Toolkit and I can tell you that it makes things a lot easier than working with plain SOAP. Good luck!

Comment: Can you please answer my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58181928/how-to-send-defaulttaxreg-with-add-customer-netsuite-soap-request

Answer (score 1):

Normally you will want to connect to the web services via API Consumer Key and Secret Token, something like this:

```
'endpoint' => env('NETSUITE_ENDPOINT'),
'host' => env('NETSUITE_HOST'),
'account' => env('NETSUITE_ACCOUNT'),
'consumerKey' => env('NETSUITE_CONSUMER_KEY'),
'consumerSecret' => env('NETSUITE_CONSUMER_SECRET'),
'token' => env('NETSUITE_TOKEN'),
'tokenSecret' => env('NETSUITE_TOKEN_SECRET'),
'signatureAlgorithm' => env('NETSUITE_SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM'),
```

This link should show you some more examples on how to obtain these tokens on your NS front page: http://mikebian.co/using-netsuites-token-based-authentication-with-suitetalk/

Answer (score 0):

Using soap webservices, you should pass the login details via the soap body. You may use user credential or token based authentication for the login. The token based authentication is recommended and it is more secured.

You may refer to this article for more information:

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/netsuitecs_gs/NSTRW/NSTRW.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwigjt6DxsbwAhVGZt4KHUwiC1oQFjACegQIBxAC&usg=AOvVaw3jqfmmyVr6PLndMQPZM8BL